# A Nine letter City

Tags: wordplay

I am a 9 letter City.

The 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th letters form an animal.

The 3rd, 4th , 7th, 8th and 9th form a body part.

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> Bucharest:

The 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th letters is an animal.

> Buc**HARE**st  - [Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hare)

The 3rd, 4th , 7th, 8th and 9th forms body part.

> Bu**CH**ar**EST**

Bonus questions for everyone else :D

> <strike>Guess where I'm writing this answer from.</strike> From which city did I post my answer?

Comment: Your workplace? ;-)

Comment: @BmyGuest. Ha ha...true. I will rephrase my bonus question,

Comment: I guess this question was pretty easy for you? :P

Comment: @Radhato. Not really. The name of the city I live in is pronounced differently in my language.

Comment: Easy one though :) Nice @Marius.

Comment: @Marius I see :) Nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer be

> **Bu**${}$***ch***${}$**ar**${}$***est*** ?

---

Comment: You do not need to include your username in the answer, as for the users who want to check your profile out can simply do it through clicking on your username. Also, make sure to write `>!` before some key words of your answer(s) to hide and not spoil the answer for other users attempting to solve the puzzle. Other than that, welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**. Since you are new to the site, I strongly suggest you visit the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and particularly look at the *Asking* and *Answering* sections, and the *Our model* section. :D

Comment: Congratulations on your very first answer on this site! I am glad you joined! I hope that you continue to answer other puzzles, and perhaps make some puzzles of your own. If you wish to share any puzzles you found, make sure to site the source. If you are to announce any potential spoilers in comments, you cannot hide it in the code, `>!`. Instead, you would have to use [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/): a site that converts text into an illegible message. For example, Rot13(Uryyb!) means to copy-and-paste **Uryyb!** into Rot13 (if you want), to view the secret message: **Hello!**. Take care! :D

Comment: Oh, and one last thing: if you want to comment to some other user, write @[their username] to notify them of your comment. Also, talking about notifications, I have proposed an edit to improve your answer, which you might have (or will shortly) be notified of :)